# facebook comment box error: The comments plugin requires an href parameter

Tags: facebook, comments

i am using facebook connect apps for facebook comment box on my website i have follow tutorial on https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/02/19/commenting-with-facebook-connect/

and put the things step by step on my website and its works fine but when i put same thing in my other website its show me this error

The comments plugin requires an href parameter.

what am i doing worng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the comment plugin with the official generator and you are fine:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

of course you need a link for the comment plugin, just take your actual page. it´s kind of a unique id for the comment plugin, so you should never change it when you got comments already.

Btw, the tutorial link you posted is from 2009. If you want to implement something, try to find a newer source next time ;)